# Have an error of project by corona sdk

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I hava a project from my friends,

When I run the project in the Eclipse ，will have an error printed in the LogCat

```
Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/ansca/corona/JavaToNativeShim;
Exception Ljava/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError; thrown while initializing Lcom/ansca/corona/CoronaEnvironment;
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b2f498)

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.uangel.corona.CoronaApplication.onCreate(CoronaApplication.java:16)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4281)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4875)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:804)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:571)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.ansca.corona.CoronaEnvironment.setLuaErrorHandler(CoronaEnvironment.java:373)
    at com.ansca.corona.CoronaEnvironment.<clinit>(CoronaEnvironment.java:41)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lua: findLibrary returned null
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
    at com.ansca.corona.JavaToNativeShim.<clinit>(JavaToNativeShim.java:94)
    ... 15 more
```

I can't make it. Please help me.

Comment: does it have error in Corona Tag?

Comment: to trace where the error comes from because he's using eclipse as his log

Answer (score 0):

I recommend seeing if you can build one of the corona sample projects first to see if you can build those.

Also some helpful information you can give us:
What version of corona are you using?